# Allow only hosts in virtual hosts using mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, server, httpd.conf

I need to allow only hosts configured on my Virtual Host.

For example: 
In my apache i have the follow config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName mydomain.or
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    Redirect 301 / https://mydomain.or
</VirtualHost>
```

The user have your own DNS server configure: www.dnsclient.or set with my ip, 
when he access the browser the insecure connection message is show, and this is what i want to block, i need that only virtual Host configured can be access.

Comment: Elaborate more on your requirement

Comment: Please elaborate more on what you need! We need details to assist you.

Comment: Done, i think that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RewriteRule inside VirtualHost.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www.mydomain.com|mydomain.or)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

This rule would only allow www.mydomain.com and mydomain.or. In Name based virtualHost if a request is received that does not match one of the specified ServerName directives, it will be served by the first  defined in the configuration files as the default.

Comment: This is a good idea, but if i have more that 200 domains with many VirtualHosts in each one, so is difficult configure to all domains. For this i think to use the VirtualHosts.